# Como hacer que las soluciones compartan las mismas clases?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wpf

Tengo una carpeta que contiene basicamente todas las clases de C# que uso y me gustaria que los 4 proyectos que tengo compartieran esas mismas clases que estan dentro de esa carpeta. No he encotrado la forma de hacerlo, las he puesto en cada proyecto por que no se como hacer que todas adopten las clases que estan ahi dentro.

- Carpeta con clases dentro
- Solucion1
- Solucion2
- Solucion3
- Solucion4

Las soluciones estan todas dentro de la misma carpetas, osea en la carpeta Soluciones estan todas las carpetas de cada solucion y la de la carpeta que necesito compartir.

Comment: Lo normal sería crear un proyecto de biblioteca de clases; lo que te generará un .DLL el cual podrás referenciar en cualquier proyecto que crees y podrás acceder a las clases que contiene.

Comment: Publiqué una respuesta a tu pregunta, alguien que no se si fuiste tu, le otorgó un punto positivo, si fuiste tu asumo que es por que la respuesta te resultó útil, si es así me gustaría que marcaras la respuesta como aceptada, mejoraría mi reputación y me permitiría poder contribuir y ayudar más a los miembros del sitio.

Comment: @EduardoReyes, aun no lo he probado, cuando lo haga y me funcione marco tu respuesta como correcta, no pasa nada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La solución a ese problema es la siguiente:
Crea un proyecto de Biblioteca (Class Library) en el agrega las clases que son comunes a todos los demás proyectos, lo compilas y te creará un archivo .dll; después en cada en cada proyecto que requiera de esas clases, agregas una referencia al archivo .dll creado.
Cuando compilas el proyecto de Biblioteca (Class Library), suponiendo que tu proyecto se llame "Carpeta_clases", el archivo .dll, generalmente estará ubicado en la siguiente ruta `Carpeta_clases\Carpeta_clases\bin\Debug\Carpeta_clases.dll`, agregas en cada proyecto una referencia a ese archivo y listo.
La forma de hacer referencia después a cada clase y sus propiedades y funciones, es la misma que empleas por ejemplo para hacer referencia a la clase `System.Windows.Forms`, esta clase no es otra cosa que una de las clase incluidas dentro de un ensamblaje ubicado generalmente en `Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.dll`.

Comment: Gracias, veo que la respuesta ha sido aceptada. Agregar que esta es la solución para cuando un que es común en varios proyectos, es la forma en que tareas muy comunes y útiles, se implementan de forma que este disponible cada ves que se necesite, un ensamblaje .dll se puede distribuir a trabes de medios de almacenaje portables o una pagina web  desde donde se puede descargar, incluso si no violas nada legal, se puede poner a la venta, siempre que haya alguien dispuesto a pagar, un desarrollador solo tendría que tenerlo en su PC y agregar una referencia para poder utilizar sus objetos.